# How to count the "yes" answers (rows with a certain value in a certain column) in a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a summary and I want to count the number of "Yes" and "No" for each suggestion:

```
Name | Cats| Dogs| Rabbits|
john | Yes | No  | No    |
max  | No  | No  | Yes   |
oli  | Yes | Yes | Yes   |
```

How I can retrieve the columns content?
`cats -> 2, dogs -> 1, rabbits -> 2`

So I am starting with something like this:

```
CSV.parse("summary.csv", header: true, col_sep: ";") do |row|
  "Cats"   => row[0]
  "Dogs"   => row[1] 
  "Rabbits" => row[2]
end
```

Comment: I suggest columns are the suggestions? In your example you want to have the result: cats -> 2, dogs -> 1, rabits -> 2? (btw, rabbits)

Comment: Yes that's it :)

Comment: Okay, this would be way to edit your question to make an okay question better! (Besides stating what else you tried and what happened when you tried :) )

Answer (score 1):

Its not a very elegant solution, but does the job in a "classic" (iteratively programmed) fashion. I stripped it of the Rails stuff, such that it is a standalone application. You will have to put your Rails-Stuff back in.

Note that your CSV example uses "|" (the pipe) as a separator.

```
require 'csv'

# Start with 0 of each
counts = {cats: 0, dogs: 0, rabbits: 0}
# run over every row
CSV.foreach("c.csv", headers: true, col_sep: "|") do |row|
  # Check answers in each column and increase count if "Yes"
  if row[1].strip == 'Yes'                                         
    counts[:cats] = counts[:cats] + 1                              
  end                                                              
  if row[2].strip == 'Yes'                                         
    counts[:dogs] = counts[:dogs] + 1                              
  end                                                              
  if row[3].strip == 'Yes'                                         
    counts[:rabbits] = counts[:rabbits] + 1                        
  end                                                              
end                                                                

puts counts # Will print {:cats=>2, :dogs=>1, :rabbits=>2}
```

Note that the CSV-Access can be greatly simplified/made more readable in many ways (see https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html). The counting and grouping, which in the example code is done by manually walking over each row and column can greatly be simplified and beautified by using methods from the Enumerable module: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html . Reading and understanding the given links will greatly improve your programming performance.

Have fun learning and hacking!

Answer (score 1):

```
csv =<<-END
Name | Cats| Dogs| Rabbits|
john | Yes | No  | No    |
max  | No  | No  | Yes   |
oli  | Yes | Yes | Yes   |
END

FNAME = 'temp.csv'
File.write(FNAME, csv)
  #=> 109
```

**Use CSV methods**

We could use [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) methods as follows.

```
require 'csv'

csv = CSV.read(FNAME, headers: true, col_sep: '|')
csv.headers.each_with_object({}) do |animal,h|
  unless animal.nil? || animal.strip == "Name"
    h[animal.strip.downcase] = csv[animal].count { |s| s.strip == "Yes" }
  end
end
  #=> {"cats"=>2, "dogs"=>1, "rabbits"=>2}
```

**Use `CSV` methods after pre-processing the file**

Using `CSV` methods is a bit cumbersome here. For one:

```
csv.headers
  #=> ["Name ", " Cats", " Dogs", " Rabbits", nil]
```

The element `nil` is there because the separator is `|` and that character appears at the end of each line. The second problem is the presence of spaces. It would be more convenient, for example, if the column label `" Cats"` were `"Cats"` or, better yet, `"cats"`.

In view of these complications, one might consider doing some simple pre-processing on the file to make it easier to apply `CSV` methods.

```
TEMP_FNAME = 'temp1.csv'    
File.write(TEMP_FNAME, File.read(FNAME).delete(' ').downcase.gsub(/\|$/,''))
  #=> 68
```

Let's see what was written.

```
puts File.read(TEMP_FNAME)
name|cats|dogs|rabbits
john|yes|no|no
max|no|no|yes
oli|yes|yes|yes
```

We can now construct the desired hash quite easily.

```
csv = CSV.read(TEMP_FNAME, headers: true, col_sep: '|')
csv.headers.each_with_object({}) do |animal,h|
  h[animal] = csv[animal].count("yes") unless animal == 'name'
end
  #=> {"cats"=>2, "dogs"=>1, "rabbits"=>2}
```

Arguably, doing this in two steps also simplifies debugging and testing.

**Treat the file as an ordinary text file**

It may be simpler yet to treat the file as an ordinary text file when, as here, its contents don't permit the straightforward use of `CSV` methods:

```
File.read(FNAME).downcase.split("\n").
     map { |line| line.split(/ *\| */)[1..] }.transpose.
     each_with_object({}) { |(lbl,*rest),h| h[lbl]=rest.count('yes') }
       #=> {"cats"=>2, "dogs"=>1, "rabbits"=>2}
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = File.read(FNAME).downcase.split("\n")
puts a
name | cats| dogs| rabbits|
john | yes | no  | no    |
max  | no  | no  | yes   |
oli  | yes | yes | yes   |

b = a.map { |line| line.split(/ *\| */)[1..] }
  #=> [["cats", "dogs", "rabbits"],
  #    ["yes", "no", "no"],
  #    ["no", "no", "yes"],
  #    ["yes", "yes", "yes"]] 
c = b.transpose
  #=> [["cats", "yes", "no", "yes"],
  #    ["dogs", "no", "no", "yes"],
  #    ["rabbits", "no", "yes", "yes"]] 
c.each_with_object({}) { |(lbl,*rest),h| h[lbl]=rest.count('yes') }
  #=> {"cats"=>2, "dogs"=>1, "rabbits"=>2}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
CSV.open("summary.csv", col_sep: ";")
  .to_a
  .transpose[1..]
  .map { |(name, *data)| [name, data.count { |val| val == "Yes" }] }
  .to_h
```

It's output:

```
{
  "Cats" => 2,
  "Dogs" => 1,
  "Rabbits" => 2
}
```

Step by step explanation:

First, let's read the data:

```
irb> CSV.open("x.csv", col_sep: ";").to_a
=> [["Name", "Cats", "Dogs", "Rabbits"], ["john", "Yes", "No", "No"], ["max", "No", "No", "Yes"], ["oli", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"]]
```

Next, transpose to have the animals and values together:

```
irb> CSV.open("x.csv", col_sep: ";").to_a.transpose
=> [["Name", "john", "max", "oli"], ["Cats", "Yes", "No", "Yes"], ["Dogs", "No", "No", "Yes"], ["Rabbits", "No", "Yes", "Yes"]]
```

Notice how the first element is not relevant, so we ignore it by appending `[1..]` to get all elements except the first.

Then we just have to convert each array element to the animal name and the count of `"Yes"` values. For a single element we can do that as follows:

```
row = ["Cats", "Yes", "No", "Yes"]
(name, *data) = row
```

`name` will be `"Cats"` and `data` will contain the other elements, i.e. it'll be `["Yes", "No", "Yes"]`.

Now we just need to count the `"Yes"` values in `data`:

```
irb> [name, data.count { |val| val == "Yes" }]
=> ["Cats", 2]
```

Using `map` we can do that on all elements of the transposed data set. Calling `#to_h` on that will use the first element of each array as the key and the second element as the value.

Comment: I didn't know one could write `[1,2,3][1..] #=> [2, 3]` as shorthand for `[1,2,3][1..-1]`. Is that something new? That's certainly convenient. I just tried `[1,2,3][..-2]` but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: @CarySwoveland endless ranges are new in Ruby 2.6: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/7f95eed19e22cb9a4867819355fe4ab99f85fd16

Answer (score 0):

First settle the data into a `table`:

```
require 'csv'

raw_table = File.read("summary.csv")
table = CSV.parse(raw_table.gsub(' ', ''), col_sep: '|', headers: true)
```

This reads the data into a string, remove spaces and parse to CSV with separator and headers.

The columns separator is `'|'`, since there is a separator on the extreme right, it generates an empty column. Then it is required to remove it, see `.compact` or `[1...-1]` used here below.

---

Then, one option os to process the table as an array of hashes:

```
h_table = table.map { |e| e.to_h.compact }
#=> [{"Name"=>"John", "Cats"=>"Yes", "Dogs"=>"No", "Rabbits"=>"No"}, {"Name"=>"Max", "Cats"=>"No", "Dogs"=>"No", "Rabbits"=>"Yes"}, {"Name"=>"Oli", "Cats"=>"Yes", "Dogs"=>"Yes", "Rabbits"=>"Yes"}]
```

Set `counts` to zero then scan the `h_table`:

```
counts = h_table.first.transform_values { |v| 0 }.tap{ |h| h.delete 'Name'}
counts #=> {"Cats"=>0, "Dogs"=>0, "Rabbits"=>0}
counts.keys.each { |k| h_table.each { |h| counts[k] += 1 if h[k] == 'Yes' } }
counts #=> {"Cats"=>2, "Dogs"=>1, "Rabbits"=>2}
```

---

Or (best option) convert to an array and process it transposed as mentioned by @fphilipe:

```
table.to_a.transpose[1...-1].each_with_object({}) { |(k, *v), h| h[k] = v.count{ |e| e == 'Yes' } }
#=> {"Cats"=>2, "Dogs"=>1, "Rabbits"=>2}
```

---

**But if the the original input is**

```
Name;Cats;Dogs;Rabbits
John;Yes;No ;No
Max;No ;No ;Yes
Oli;Yes;Yes;Yes
```

Just use `table = CSV.read("summary.csv", col_sep: ';', headers: true)` then apply one of the mentioned methods, **just without removing the empty column**.

Comment: The gsub is okay for the given example data but not good if e.g. Name can contain spaces. For that case, it would be better to use CSVs built-in `strip`ping (which I would have to lookup myself, but I remember that it is possible).

Comment: @Felix, my answer is tailored for the specific data input showed in the OP question (pipe separator and lots of spaces).  `strip` is not enough in that case. But maybe the real data input is different.

Comment: Looking at the docs, I think I misremember something. Probably usually one would use a converter. However, regarding the empty column, maybe "skip_blanks" would help: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new . **Edit** Forget about that; `skip_blanks` will skip empty rows, not columns (which would be weird).